# Notation for a countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a set $A$ is countable, would it be wrong to write that $A\equiv\mathrm{N}$?

Comment: How do you define countable? Is $\{1,2\}$ a countable set?

Comment: @ε-δ Countable defined as: If there exists a one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers, and the term countable refers to a set that is either finite or countably infinite.

Comment: What you wrote is a contradiction? Bijective with the natural numbers but possibly finite...

Comment: @Miski123 I assumed (in my short answer) you meant "countably infinite", since the all-too-obvious anwser is "no" if $A$'s cardinality is finite. e.g., suppose $A$ is the even integers. Then "yes". And even "yes" (wrt my answer) if $A$'s the prime numbers, because you can program a one-to-one map both ways, even though there's no closed-form function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countable often indicates a set which can be put in bijection with a subset of $\Bbb N$, id est a set which is either finite or in bijection with $\Bbb N$, whereas a countable and infinite set is called *countably ininite*. With this convention I would advise against using the symbol $\equiv$, which is usually reserved for equivalence relations, to indicate a condition which is essentially an inequality (more specifically, a condition which is not symmetric).

Answer (score 0):

Countable presumably means there's a one-to-one map, whereby you'd be tempted to answer "yes". And that might be right. But suppose there's no such **computable** function (or suppose it's computable one way, but not the inverse). Then I'm not sure if "yes" for $\equiv$ would still be considered the right answer. Probably not for constructive mathematics in particular, but I'm not sure about more generally.